# Data type mistmatch for 1459938216056250401717267022 in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE_LEADS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LEADS
        + " (leadId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,leadName TEXT,leadNumber INTEGER,leadRequirement TEXT,leadCity TEXT,leadTime TEXT,leadSource TEXT,isProcessed INTEGER);";

leadId =data.getString("id");
```

Error:

```
04-06 15:53:37.902 1802-5282/com.zip_first.zipfirst E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 6: [INSERT INTO LEADS(leadCity,leadName,leadId,leadNumber,leadRequirement,leadTime,leadSource) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
04-06 15:53:37.972 1802-5282/com.zip_first.zipfirst E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting leadCity=    Nashik   leadName=    Abhishek    leadId=1459938216056250401717267022 leadNumber=8888884678 leadRequirement=    Language Classes For English American leadTime=    Tue 24 Mar 2015 19:50:47    leadSource=justdial
                                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:906)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                                                                          at com.zip_first.zipfirst.provider.StubProvider.insert(StubProvider.java:165)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:866)
                                                                          at com.zip_first.zipfirst.gcm.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:88)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-06 15:53:37.972 1802-5282/com.zip_first.zipfirst D/MyGcmListenerService: Record inserted
04-06 15:53:37.982 1802-5282/com.zip_first.zipfirst D/Count: Count1
```

Comment: You're using type INTEGER as leadId but '1459938216056250401717267022' is type of LONG but in SQLite there is no LONG datatype so you can use TEXT datatype instead of INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, integers cannot have more than 64 bits, so the largest possible value is 9223372036854775807.

If you really want to use 1459938216056250401717267022 as ID, you have to change the table to use a text column.